# SSL error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

ERROR:

```
SSL error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

STEPS:

```
openssl genrsa -out SITE.TLD.key 2048
openssl req -new -key SITE.TLD.key -out SITE.TLD.csr
```

(send CSR to SSL site to sign)

```
add CERT to SITE.TLD.crt
add CA to SITE.TLD.ca
```

chained them:

```
cat SITE.TLD.crt SITE.TLD.ca > chained.cert
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong? I am using LiteSpeed HTTPd

Answer (score 4):

First check that private key indeed matches by looking at the modulus
    diff <(openssl rsa -in KEY -modulus -noout) <(openssl x509 -in CERT -modulus -noout)
should produce no output

Comment: What happens if it does produce stuff?

Comment: Then it your private key don't match the certs signing key. That means that you have to find the correct key or repeat the whole process again. I.e generate a key ,csr and send it off to your certificate provider

Comment: I've gone through the process 4 times now. Same results.

Comment: Hmm it might you certificate provider then, I've only used a few but if there is online form that you use it might be that you selecting wrong certificate options. I suggest contacting their support, to make sure you doing everything right with keys and CSR you might want to generate a cert yourself openssl x509 -req -days 30 -in SITE.TLD.csr -signkey SITE.TLD.key -out YOURs.crt the check i've suggested in the answer should work then

Answer (score 0):

Double check the content of your certificate.

This is probably not a solution for all, but at least it solved my problem when I got the same error.

I copy/pasted the certificate from an e-mail I got from the CA. After taking a closer look at what I actually copy pasted, I realised that every line had a leading space. After removing these everything works fine.